# printing out strings in reverse

Tags: assembly, mips

```
   .data 
 str: .asciiz "Hello Sir"  
.text 

la $a0, str # load the address of the string 
addi $t0, $a0, 0 # starting address of array 
#TODO: find length of string, it's zero terminated, so loop until a zero 

strLen:                 #getting length of string
lb      $t1, str($t2)   #loading value
add     $t2, $t2, 1
bne     $t1, $zero, strLen
sub     $t2, $t2, 1
li      $v0, 11         #load imediate - print low-level byte



addi $t1, $a0, 21 # initialize loop counter to array end position
loop: lb $a0, 0($t0) # load a single character 
  li $v0, 11 # specify print character service 3 
  syscall # print 
  addi $t0, $t0, 1 # add 1 to the loop index 
  blt $t0, $t1, loop # continue if not at string length 


Loop:
sub     $t2, $t2, 1
la      $t1, str($t2)   #loading value
lb      $a0, ($t1)
syscall

bnez    $t2, Loop
  li $v0, 10 # system call for exit 
  syscall # we are out of here.
```

I want to create code that will print out the string and also print out its reverse. e.g "Hello SirriS olleH". How would I change this line

```
  addi $t1, $a0, 21 # initialize loop counter to array end position
```

so that it initalizes to the length of the given string rather than setting to 21 by default. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you already have `strLen` which produces the string length in `$t2` you can just use that register in the comparison directly. You could of course copy it to `$t1` too if you wanted, but there isn't much point in doing that.

Side note: it might make sense to print the forward string in your `strLen` loop so you can get rid of the second loop.

Finally, I recommend you use better labels, `loop` and `Loop` are not very informative and using labels that only differ in case is a bad idea anyway.